# Why the loop of "While ... do ... done" can't read a text file?

Tags: bash, text-files

The job I want to do is reading a line from a text file(currently this file only contains a line, the number of lines will be increased later) with the loop of "While ... do ... done". The weird thing is it can only read some of text files. My code is :

```
...(previous commands to create "myfile.txt")...
while read -r line
do
 echo "flag" 
done < "myfile.txt"
```

I have tried a few cases. If I replaced the "myfile.txt" by another file "test.txt" which is created by hand in current directory(this "test.txt" contains one line either), my script can print "flag".

Similarly, after "myfile.txt" has been created, if I modify and save it in current directory, then run my script, it can print "flag" normally either.

Other cases except above two, my script can't print "flag". 
I also tried to "chmod" and "touch" the text file in my script, like following, it can't work either.

Obviously, I hope my script read the line(s) of a text file, can anybody please tell me the reason and give a solution ?

BTW, this file can be read by cat command.

```
...(previous commands to create "myfile.txt")...
chmod 777 "myfile.txt"
touch "myfile.txt"
cat "myfile.txt" #(I can see the results of this line)
while read -r line
do
 echo "flag" 
done < "myfile.txt"
```

Thanks !

the whole code of creating the text file is around 800 lines. However, I'd like to post the lines which create my text file. Here they are:

```
  for(i = 1, i<=6, ++i){ 
    ...
    ofstream myfile("myfile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
     ...
    if(myfile.is_open()){
       myfile << "rms_" << std::setprecision(3) << RMS_values ;
       myfile.close();
    }
  }
```

**************** Beginning of my solution  ****************************************

Thanks for above replies.

I have solved by myself and this link :  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/what-does-the-noeol-indicator-at-the-bottom-of-a-vim-edit-session-mean

The reason is in my script of producing the text file, there is no "\n" at the end. So, the text file has a "[noeol]" icon after the filename when opened in VI.

According to the above link, if there is no "[noeol]", UNIX/LINUX won't read this file.

The solution is rather simple(looking afterwards), just add "<< "\n" " at the end of "cout". The line becomes,

```
 myfile << "rms_" << std::setprecision(3) << RMS_values << "\n";
```

**************** End of my solution  ****************************************

Comment: i dont know `bash`scripting but i guess that maybe after your creation of the file, the buffer was not flushed and so the file was not entirely written

Comment: Your script works correctly for me - how do you create the file?

Comment: @Zaiborg: File can only be not flushed within a single process. Since each shell command is separate process, this is not a concern.

Comment: Can you post a [Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/)? What you posted does not demonstrate any error at all.

Comment: @JoshJolly, As I mentioned above, if the text file(in my cases is "myfile.text") is created under current directory, it works well for me either.

Comment: @JoshJolly, While in my case, I run a bash script to run a C++ script under another directory to produce the "myfile.txt". This produced text file is in the same directory of my bash script(not the same one as C++ script), and I need this "myfile.txt" for further analysis.

Comment: @user2740039: The internals of the C++ part is irrelevant. It is only relevant things are whether the C++ tool already finished, left the file where you are looking for it and whether the file is non-empty, with appropriate permissions (but it should be if it's all running as one user) and contains lines separated by the newline character so the `read` command can meaningfully split it.

Comment: @JanHudec This is likely only true of external commands - `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc... I'm very sure things like `while`, `echo`, `test` and other `bash` builtins do not run as separate processes, so it's not unreasonable to wonder if there are some weird buffering issues going on...

Comment: @twalberg: The tool generating the file is external command. If it exited before the while loop, buffering issues are not possible. And as for built in commands, yes, they use the same stream, but a buffering issue would mean a bug in the built-in command and that is not very likely.

Comment: solution should not be added to the question but as an answer

Answer (score 1):

**$** `cat test.sh`

```
#!/bnin/bash
echo "content" > "myfile.txt"
cat "myfile.txt" #(I can see the results of this line)
while read -r line
do
 echo "flag" 
done < "myfile.txt"
```

**$** `bash test.sh`

```
content
flag
```

**$**

It works. There is no problem with it. The script is exact copy of what you posted except the touch is replaced with some content, because the while loop prints one message per line in the file, so **if there are no lines** (and `touch` won't add any), **it will obviously print nothing.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess here:

In Unix, two assumptions are made about text files:

- All lines end in a `<LF>` character. If you edit your file on an old, old Mac which used `<CR>`, Unix won't see the line endings. If you edit a file on Windows programs like `Notepad.exe`, your lines will end in `<CR><LF>` and Unix will assume the `<CR>` is part of the line.
- All lines must end in a `<LF>`, including the last line. If you write a program using a C program, the last line may not end in a `<LF>` unless you specifically write it out.

Unix utilities like `awk`, `grep`, and shells live and breath on these assumptions. When someone usually tells me something doesn't quite work when reading a file using a shell script, I tell them to edit that file in `VIM` and then save it (thus forcing an ending `<LF>` character). In VIM, you need to `:set ff=unix` and then save. That usually takes care of the issue.

My guess is that your file you're reading in doesn't have the correct line endings, and/or that the last line doesn't have that `<LF>` character on the end.

Comment: my case JUST as you guessed. See the last section of my post above please.

Comment: @user2740039 Don't forget to accept David's answer then! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question - can you show us more code/how you create the file?

Here is a working example:

```
$ cat readfile.sh
#!/bin/bash

{
        cat <<EOT
this
is
a
test
file
EOT
} > ./test.txt

while read -r line; do
        echo "line = [${line}]"
done <./test.txt
```

.

```
$ ./readfile.sh
line = [this]
line = [is]
line = [a]
line = [test]
line = [file]
```